# MySQL calculating time difference when one data point is null

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, jasper-reports

I have a query that runs on a patient record system:

```
SELECT WardTransactions.Id ID, 
       Genders.Description Gender, 
       Wards.Code Ward, 
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(DischargeDateTime, AdmissionDateTime)) Duration
from WardTransactions
JOIN Wards on WardTransactions.WardId=Wards.Id
JOIN Demographics on WardTransactions.DemographicId=Demographics.Id
JOIN Genders on Demographics.GenderId=Genders.Id
JOIN Visits on WardTransactions.VisitId=Visits.Id
```

The Issue is that at the time the query is run, DischargeDateTime may be null as the patient is still in the ward.  I need to include that record in the calculation, but have the DischargeDateTime set to the current time.  I intend to use the Duration data in a jasperReports variable to calculate total, max, min and average times.

I am not sure how to build a query to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT WardTransactions.Id ID, 
       Genders.Description Gender, 
       Wards.Code Ward, 
       TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(
       (case WHEN DischargeDateTime IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE DischargeDateTime END), AdmissionDateTime)) Duration
from WardTransactions
JOIN Wards on WardTransactions.WardId=Wards.Id
JOIN Demographics on WardTransactions.DemographicId=Demographics.Id
JOIN Genders on Demographics.GenderId=Genders.Id
JOIN Visits on WardTransactions.VisitId=Visits.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, you want `NOW()` to be used as the discharge timestamp if the patient isn't yet discharged.

Use this expression:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(DischargeDateTime,NOW()), AdmissionDateTime)) Duration
```

and you'll get what you need.

Comment: Thank you for this - it seems to work as well and is a little shorter